# Can a Scala object reference itself in its constructor?

Tags: scala

I want to construct an object, but in the process I want to pass itself in as one of the parameters during construction.

```
object TradeTable extends AbstractTable (
  join = ReportForeignKey.addJoinTo(TradeTable).withAlias(TradeTableJoin.Parent)
)
```

I get an error

```
super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless parameter is declared by-name
```

I tried using `this` but that doesn't work either. I think I can convert this to a class and it works then but I only need a single instance of this ever.

Comment: @senia you are referencing the object in the body, not the constructor of the class being extended.

Comment: what about doing that after defining the object? Like `object TradeTable extends AbstractTable;
 ReportForeignKey.addJoinTo(TradeTable).withAlias(TradeTableJoin.Parent)` I'm a beginner on scala so if this doesn't make sense it's normal :p

Comment: Just tried this Scala 2.10.3 and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @RobN would you mind answering the question then?